# Can I deploy bot developed using Composer without using Azure?

Tags: azure, composer-php, botframework

can I deploy/ publish bot developed using Composer without using Azure ? I want to deploy it on a website or skype , but without using Azure services ? Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, Azure Bot Services built in Composer need to be deployed to Azure since they rely on Azure Web Apps, Azure Functions, and other components like LUIS. You can deploy to Azure but embed / link to it from your web site to give a seamless experience.

Comment: Can it be deployed on azure but without using composer? I am looking to setup CICD to do so..

Comment: Sure - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-cicd